# Xpath element not found

Tags: selenium

I can't find my link using this Xpath `//a[contains(text(),'My stuff')]`

Though I can find it through DOM :

HTML :

```
<li _ngcontent-c8="">
  <a _ngcontent-c8="" href="my-stuff">
    {" "}
    My Stuff{" "}
  </a>
</li>;
```

[image]

When executed :

```
try:
    my_stuff = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'My stuff')]"))
    )
    my_stuff.click()
except:
    print("not found")
```

returns not found

---

There was a modal messing with my selection that needed to be dissmissed.

Comment: that is a text node, you can not use this xpath `//a[contains(text(),'My stuff')]` in selenium to extract the text off of it. Since Selenium use `XPath v.1`, Update the question with relevant HTML.

Comment: same happens if I try the href attribute "//a[contains(@href,'my-stuff')]"

Comment: It's hard to tell what error you are running into without seeing the website or HTML.

Comment: sorry, updated. This is the best I can do as the website is only accessible with credentials :/

Comment: Thanks, I will need bit more outer html to give you a relevant locator.

Comment: Nevermind, there was a modal overlay which was messing with my selectors apparently :)

Comment: There was a modal messing with my selection that needed to be dissmissed.

Answer (score 1):

i will try to analyse the problem and give you most answer

. first : if you have Xpath Helper "google chrome extension" try to put your Xpath there

=> if you find it then the problem in your code . we will try to change it

=> if you can't find it with Xpath helper ,than there is multiple choice:

first try to find if there is a "table" or new "form" above your Xpath , that you can't get it with absolute path
. you must get inside the "table" or "form", then find the path inside it
, tell me if that didn't work

Comment: xpath helper is gold, thank you !!

Comment: Did you find a solution ?